# Reorder Not working from admin Magento 2

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, reorder

I am going to generate reorder from admin. When i click on submit Order button the page will be stuck at "loading..." and never finish.
Can you guys let me know what is the issue actually?

Payment Method: Authorize.net credit card.
Shipping Method: USA (FEDEX GROUND).

Please see this screenshot.

[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: have you checked console when loading ?

Comment: Please check this screenshot.https://bit.ly/2QIYQYt  I can't see in the console screen after click on submit order.

Comment: Check console errors near inspector

Comment: I have checked both.If i enabled check/Money order and try to place an order then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

- You can not **reorder** from admin if you don't enter credit card
  details.
- If you have customer's credit card details then you can place an
  order from the admin by `authorize.net` payment method.
- Otherwise you must select **offline payment method** like `COD` ,
  `check/Money` order.

Comment: Hi Can u please advise https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292904/magento-2-reorder-functionality-missing-for-migrated-orders